# Whassup with this ceiling fixture?

Tags: fluorescent, ballast

40W Circline fluorescent would periodically light for less than a second, but stay on when tried an hour or so later. Replaced bulb; same problem. Replaced ballast; now it lights for only about a second every time. Connections and ground seem good.

Comment: Could you get the model number for the ballast and the lamp, a mis match can cause issues.

Comment: Does it have a **Starter**?  Since the behavior changed when you changed the ballast, might you have miswired it?  New ballasts don't necessarily wire like old ones.

Comment: Ballast is Model CH40-120B (same as original), lamp is Circline FC40T5/835. No starter. I guessed that the two yellow feed wires are interchangeable; not so?

Comment: Turns out the model number was correct, but the suffix to it (three lines further down on the label) was incorrect. The right ballast is on its way; fingers crossed.